# PHP PCRE - get city from address

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need to get from a full address the last words it contains, after the postal code (which should always be in the same order).

An example of an address:

```
Av. Elias Garcia (em frente ao Restaurante Pote) Palhais 2815-233 Charneca da Caparica
```

I need to get this part:

```
Charneca da Caparica
```

which, as you can see, is the last words after the postal code:

```
2815-233
```

I need a PCRE expression to match this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the postal code always in "4 digits - 3 digits", numbers only format?

Comment: Affirmative @deceze. Now that you asked, that format is for Portugal. Hope it helps anyone in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should be able to do it.

```
preg_match('/\d{4}-\d{3}\s+(.*)/', $subject, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

PS: I wouldn't try to parse this using reg exp because it won't be efficient, what if the user put the city before the zip code. If you are 100% sure of your data it should be fine.

Comment: @RageZ, good update. Your original expression was backwards. +1 on the PS. This is a very specific regex.

Comment: Damn I was close. I don't have control over the user input, this is for a web crawler, but I'm trusting (too naive?) that the original application controls that part for me. By the way, you're missing the last slash at the end of the expression. Cheers!

Comment: I think you a word and delimiter there. ;)

Comment: You still a word in your last sentence, I think. :o)

Answer (score 2):

This will get the last part of the string after the postal code (4 digits, dash, 3 digits) and whitespace.

```
preg_match('/\s+\d{4}-\d{3}\s+(.+)$/', $address, $match);
print_r($match);
```